# Flink restarts - how to go through main function again

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm running a flink kinesis analytics application.
I've seen that using checkpoints is problematic for us because it causes duplicates (as indeed specified in flink documentation - `"data that has been written since that checkpoint will be written to Kinesis again"`).

However, when trying to work without checkpoints if the app is restarted it starts reading from the beginning of the stream.
I have a code in the main function to specify where to start reading the stream (i.e. 3 hours back) but the main function is not called in the restart process.

Is there a way to tell the app where to start reading the stream after restarting (and not only when manually stopping and starting the app)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by overriding FlinkKinesisConsumer and overriding method createFetcher where I can set the timestamp in the config map passed.

```
@Override
protected KinesisDataFetcher<T> createFetcher(
        List<String> streams,
        SourceFunction.SourceContext<T> sourceContext,
        RuntimeContext runtimeContext,
        Properties configProps,
        KinesisDeserializationSchema<T> deserializationSchema) {

    int hours = 3;
    long newInitPos = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - (hours * 3600);
    configProps.setProperty(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(newInitPos));

    return new KinesisDataFetcher<>(streams, sourceContext, runtimeContext, configProps, deserializationSchema,
            getShardAssigner(), getPeriodicWatermarkAssigner(), getWatermarkTracker());
}
```